# chrome: disabling windows.open link event bound with .live

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnChangeSelectField(obj) 
    {
    location.href=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    }


                $(document).live('click', function(e)
    {
        if (e.target.nodeName.toString().toLowerCase() == 'body')
        {
            window.open('/?group_id=534&postedBySearchForm=On&srcMinPrice=0&srcMaxPrice=1135309&srcBrnd[]=1000054&srcFtr_114=-1&srcFtr_116=-1', '_self');
        }
    });
```

how can I disable (using chrome browser) the click event in the above example ?
thanks

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` do not work?

Comment: You should probably using `.on()` too, `.live()` has been depreciated since jQuery 1.7. this would also allow you to use `.off()` - http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: I want only disable this code (not mine) injecting some javascript code in the page